# How to change the value of a variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables, overriding

I am building a RPG character generator and am having a semi-difficult time with the stats of the character. The reason I am having issues is this:

```
      int base = 10;

      int iStrengthStatPoints =  scan.nextInt();

      int iStrength = (base +iStrengthStatPoints);
```

It won't compile because I am outputting the variable "iStrength" later in my code and it says cannot find symbol. I realize it is due to having iStrength being set to the value of base + iStrengthStatPoints. So I am wondering if there is a way I can assign a starting value to iStrengthStatPoints and then have the option to input a new value later on.

The thought I had was something like this:

```
      int iStrengthStatPoints = 0;

      int iStrengthStatPoints =  scan.nextInt();
```

It would have the base value 0 but later on I could input an overriding value. Is this possible? If not is there a way to do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compiler is saying that it cannot find the symbol, you are trying to print `iStrength` out of its scope.  Chances are you are declaring the variable in one method, giving it scope local to the method, and then trying to print it later in another method.  This would be true even of variables declared in the class's constructor.

Comment: I have the variable iStrength declared and initialized in one case of a switch statement and it printed out in another case. It is in the same method though. Would it being in different cases be an issue?

Comment: As described, no.  In general, each case in a switch does not constitute its own scope.  For proper diagnosis, it would be good to provide both the context of your declaration (just a bit more than you've already done) and also the error you are getting form your compiler

Comment: I have two switch statements and the variables are declared in one and printed in another.

In case 1 of my second switch statement I have: 

     int iStrengthStatPoints = 0;


     iStrengthStatPoints =  scan.nextInt();


     int iStrength = (base +iStrengthStatPoints);


In case 2 of my first switch statement I have: 


     System.out.println("Your strength: " +iStrength);

The error is "Cannot find symbol iStrength". Will it being in two different switch statements be a problem?

Comment: Yes.  The curly braces will denote scope in that case.  I would declare the variable at the start of your method.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to *declare* the variable (using the `int` keyword or other type-name) once; after that, you can *assign* to it (change its value) many times. So, this is fine:

```
      int iStrengthStatPoints = 0;
```

and you just need to change this:

```
      int iStrengthStatPoints =  scan.nextInt();
```

to this:

```
      iStrengthStatPoints =  scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine however I can't print out iStrength but it is no longer giving me issues with it being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the assignment statement that updates `iStrength`.  Rather, it is with the scoping of the declaration `iStrength`.  More precisely, the `iStrength` identifier is *out of scope* at the point you are trying to print it.

Unfortunately, neither the declaration or the problematic print code are in your code snippet, so it is not possible to say exactly what the problem is and how to fix it.  Even guessing what the problem might be is futile, because there are (in general ... i.e. without seeing your code) too many possibilities.

If you want a better diagnosis, include (at least) everything from the declaration to the code that is giving the compilation error.